# How to find out the index of value in list?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list with floats and I am looking for an index of the value in the interval (5-eps;5+eps). How to do that please? This gives me an error about types: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

```
import numpy as np

LIST = [4.1, 5.02, 4.99999, 5.00001]
eps = 0.001
index, = np.where((LIST < 5+eps) & (LIST > 5-eps))
print('Index', index)
```

Comment: Did you test elements of that `where` expression?  Does `LIST < 5+eps` work?  Remember in Python, arguments of a function are evaluated first, and the results passed in.  So you have to get the condition expression working first.  `where` just tells us where the condition is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a numpy array.

```py
import numpy as np

LIST = [4.1, 5.02, 4.99999, 5.00001]
np_list = np.array(LIST)
eps = 0.001
index, = np.where((np_list < 5+eps) & (np_list > 5-eps))
print('Index', index)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Index [2 3]
```